# how to update state from a react-native web form?

Tags: forms, react-native

I have a form that lets a user create a note. The form has inputs for a name, title, and time. I want to append all of these to my state as an object representing another note. My current state looks like this:

```
state = {
    notes: [
      {
        text: "mow the lawn",
        author: "dean",
        time: "10am"
      },
      {
        text: "feed the dog",
        author: "sam",
        time: "2pm"
      }
    ]
  };
```

I have a form where a user can make a new note but I'm not familar with the best practice for pulling the form data in react-native and appending it to the state (which is an array). The code below is my current attempt.

```
//FUNCTION IN MAIN COMPONENT TO UPDATE STATE
updateNotes = e => {
    let Notes = this.state.notes;
    Notes.push(e.target.value);
    console.log(Notes);
    this.setState({ notes: Notes });
  };

//INSIDE MY COMPONENT WHERE A USER CREATES A NOTE

            <form >
                <label>{"title"}</label>
                <input placeholder={"what will you do?"} />

                <label>{"name"}</label>
                <input placeholder={"your name"} />

                <label>{"when"}</label>
                <input placeholder={"ex: 10:00am"} />

                <Button
                  onPress={e => {
                    this.props.updateNotes(e);
                    this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                  }}
                  title={"cancel"}
                />

                <Button
                  onPress={e => {
                    this.props.updateNotes(e);
                    this.setModalVisible(true);
                  }}
                  title={"submit"}
                >
                  {" "}
                </Button>
              </form>
```

I understand there are some fundamental errors with this code. I've been looking around for a form example in react-native that's not involving validation or using a component library. So if someone could point me to a simple example I would also be most appreciative! Thanks!

Comment: your code is react web not react native

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am using code sandbox and react native web

Comment: why you refusing using a component library.

Comment: @israrel I mainly wanted to build it for my own knowledge. I didn’t want to use a component library as my first option. If you can recommend a personal favorite I’ll check it out though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can recommend you about library
[React Native Formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-formik)
She works especially well in combination with [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#mixeddefaultvalue-any-schema)

With the great explanations
[here](https://dev.to/amanhimself/build-and-validate-forms-in-react-native-using-formik-and-yup-54oc) 
and
[here](https://medium.com/swlh/forms-in-react-native-with-formik-and-yup-the-hooks-way-246aba04e740?)

> Forms are very verbose in React, and a lot of the time, you end up copy pasting a lot of boilerplate.
>
> This repository is a set of high order components designed to help you take control again of your forms with React Native and Formik

for Example

```
// Formik React Native example with "yup"

import * as yup from 'yup';

import React from 'react';
import {Button, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';
import {Formik} from 'formik';

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .label('Email')
    .email('Enter a valid email')
    .required('Please enter a registered email'),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .label('Password')
    .required()
    .min(4, 'Password must have at least 4 characters '),
});

const MyReactNativeForm = props => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{email: ''}}
    onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}>
    {({handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors, touched}) => (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
          onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
          value={values.email}
          placeholder="Enter email"
        />
        <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{touched.email && errors.email}</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
          onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
          placeholder="Enter password"
          secureTextEntry
        />
        <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
          {touched.password && errors.password}
        </Text>

        <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
      </View>
    )}
  </Formik>
);
export default MyReactNativeForm;
```